# iOS 13: Cache for UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, wwdc

In the brand-new and pretty neat `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` - how could the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` be cached upon initial creation?

All the known methods and properties seem to be on-board since the new layout class inherits from `UICollectionViewLayout`.

Looking back to the "old" custom `UICollectionViewLayout` approach the path for such a task was to my knowledge to use the method prepare() to populate a(n) array(s) with custom-made `[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]`.

From my understanding the new layout class creates the layout section-by- section returning `-> NSCollectionLayoutSection` from what we have seen as the `createLayout()` method in the WWDC19 talk [Advances in Collection View Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/215/). And it seems to do that only once at initialisation.

Now, I have subclassed a `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` and the class returns `layoutAttributesForElements` as one would expect:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let superAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        print("I am returning attributes: ", supersAttributes)
        return superAttributes
}
```

*But since they are **not** created manually, where can I initially catch these attributes, all at once, to add to a cache array?*

The reason for this path is that I am trying to re-create a very, very -high collectionViewLayout which I need zoomable. And this only got (at least in the past) performant by using a cache, modifying cached attributes during zoon and returning `layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)` from the cache all the way through the life-cycle. 
A technique I have seen at Ray Wenderlich´s tuturials and in other places.

Any input would be great! Let's have some fun understanding the new and easier world of wrangling collectionViews!

Thanks a lot for reading.

Comment: did you find any solution for this ? i need the same thing